# How does Linq-to-Xml convert objects to strings?

Tags: xml, linq, serialization, linq-to-xml, tostring

Linq-to-Xml contains lots of methods that allow you to add arbitrary objects to an xml tree.  These objects are converted to strings by some means, but I can't seem to find the specification of how this occurs.  The conversion I'm referring to is mentioned (but not specified) [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx).

I happen to need this for javascript interop, but that doesn't much matter to the question.

Linq to Xml isn't just calling `.ToString()`.  Firstly, it'll accept `null` elements, and secondly, it's doing things no `.ToString()` implementation does:

For example:

```
new XElement("elem",true).ToString() == "<elem>true</elem>"
//but...
true.ToString() == "True" //IIRC, this is culture invariant, but in any case...
true.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == "True"
```

Other basic data types are similarly specially treated.

So, does anybody know what it's doing and where that's described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't find MSDN documentation to support this, when you do something like `new XElement("bla",false)` the `System.Xml.XmlConvert` class is uses to (de-)serialize the data in a non-localized fashion.

In other words, if anyone else needs to know what exactly linq to xml does when you add a (non-xml) object into an xml tree, look at `System.Xml.XmlConvert`.

Answer (score 1):

Earmon, you are correct.

A quick visit with [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com)*** reveals that `XElement` and friends will try to cast the value to all the 'simple' types, and then call an appropriate `XmlConvert.ToString()` method.

Here's an (slightly edited) excerpt, for illustration:

```
if (value is string)
{
    str = (string) value;
}
else if (value is double)
{
    str = XmlConvert.ToString((double) value);
}
// ...
```

If the object is not a 'simple' type, then obj.ToString() will be used.

This is very nice, because that's almost the only right way to do it.

Of course, you normally want to take with a grain of salt anything based on "that's how it is today". Indeed, MS might one day change how they do it. We don't care -- what matters is that the semantics are carved in stone.

**(Product links are always provided for convenience. I have no relationship with the product or its manufacturer, other than being an indirect customer.)*

***Update:***
In [Introducing Microsoft LINQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623910), Pialorsi and Russo confirm this for the other side of the equation (extracting values and casting them), on page 172:

> [when casting an XElement to a given type like Decimal] ...the various *Explicit* [cast] operator overloads internally use *XmlConvert* from *System.Xml* or *Parse* methods of .NET types.